# Android passing data not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having two activities. The 1st one is ActOne and the second is ActTwo.See both activities here:
[image: ActOne]

[image: ActTwo]

In ActOne when i enter a no and hit generates it calculates the fatorial of that no and display it in the TextView below generate button.So this works fine.Now when i hit Generate fibo.. button , then it stores the fibonacci series in an array.Now i have to display this series in the next activity but as soon as i hit generate button it doesn't swicth to another activity and stops saying "Unfortunately FirstProject has stopped." 
So what am i doing wrong here.Below i am pasting the code as well as logcat:

```
public class ActOne extends Activity
{
Button generate,genfact;
EditText input;
TextView factans;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    generate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);
    genfact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.genfact);
    input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    factans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.factans);
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          int no=new Integer(input.getText().toString()).intValue();
          int fact=1;
          while(no>0)
          {
              fact=fact*no;
              no--;
          }
          factans.setText("The factorial is"+fact);
        }
    });

   genfact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           int no=new Integer(input.getText().toString()).intValue();
           int[] series = new int[no];
           for(int i=2; i < no; i++){
               series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];
           }
           Intent intent = new Intent(ActOne.this, ActTwo.class);
           Bundle b = new Bundle();
           b.putIntArray("array",series);
           intent.putExtras(b);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
 }
}
```

Here is the ActTwo activity

```
public class ActTwo extends Activity {
    TextView fiboans;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fiboans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fiboans);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    String[] arrRecd = b.getStringArray("array");
    fiboans.setText(String.valueOf(arrRecd[2]));
  }
}
```

Also i would like to know how to print entire array into textView ?

Here is my error logcat:

```
12-19 11:28:38.912: ERROR/Trace(1133): error opening trace file: No such file or        directory (2)
   12-19 11:29:20.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.FIrstProject/com.example.FIrstProject.ActTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.FIrstProject.ActTwo.onCreate(ActTwo.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3):

As you trying to pass IntegerArray from sender activity as `b.putIntArray("array",series);` but getting string arrays from intent at receiving side instead of integer array.

Change your reeving side to `extras.getIntArray("array")`

Answer (score 3):

In ActTwo activity first you need to set `setContentView(R.layout.yourfile);` then after you can access `fiboans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fiboans);`.

So add your view after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

After that if your problem not solved then do as @Ram Kiran Says.

Comment: thanks it's working partially. Now the second activity is displayed but the series is not displayed correctly.FOr example i had entered 4 in the first textbox in 1st activity.And the fibonacci series that was printed in the second activity is: [l@41029478

Comment: @user1788048 First print value of series in first activity and let me know what it prints

Comment: if i print it in first activity, then it prints [l@4102b2b0

Comment: @user1788048 then there must be a problem at your side . please check your code again.

Comment: i forgot to add two lines in the fibonacci code, so i added it and now also it gives the wrong series

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is some problem with printing array in a TextView . When i intialized an array with some values and tried to display it into a textview then also, it's not displaying properly.